# Leased worker: Better position, same company, 2 different hiring companies, not yet started

Tags: job-offer, job-change, counter-offer

I have signed a contract [P1] as a lease employee for H company [H] with middle-man [M1] (Lease and employment both start at the same time).

I have the second and final face-to-face interview with another manager at the same company for another position [P2] through another middle-man [M2]. This has better benefits and responsibilities.

- [P2] manager knows that he is taking me from another contract, but not that it is in the same company.

  - Middle-man [M2] knows everything
- [P1] and middle-man [M1] does not have any heads-up
- My notice period for [M1, P1] during probation is 2 weeks
- [P2] has been open for 1 year and could not be filled.
- Going under the radar is not possible since employee account is already created.

Question:

- What bridges if any will be burnt with

  - Manager [P1]
  - Middle-man [M1]
  - Hiring company [H]
- Is it okay to try to solicit better offer from [M1, P1]
- Better course of action?

  - Call before meeting and explain the situation and see if manager [P2] is still interested?

Comment: You should not have accepted the position signed the contract if you were not ready to commit to that job.

Comment: I agree with @keshlam, once signed you should stay there.  If the company wants to TRANSFER you, that's another thing.

Comment: And if you hadn't been continuing to interview after signing, you could say "hey, I know this is what I committed to, but I hear the Gomblewidget group is desperate for someone with my skill set: would it make sense to transfer me over there?" But you have put yourself in an awkward position to bring that up with the team you signed into. Best suggestion I have, then is to tell the second team "I've committed to the Varflesystem group, but I'd really like to work with you in the future; maybe you could talk with them about when it would be  appropriate to consider having me transfer over "

Answer (score 2):

I went to the interview at P2. I was open with the new manager and explained the situation. He said "It is business and strictly professional. I am sure the other manager is also a professional"

I am posting this, in case someone is in a similar position, do not be discouraged by the comments.

This is business. There is a probation period, where the manager is entitled to let you go for absolutely zero reasons.
It works both ways. If anything, you have saved him the time for the induction followed by the handover.
It is your obligation to put food on the table. Giving up on a better offer means you have brought one less plate to the family **your** family.

Comment: Yeah, not really a time to worry about burning bridges, it's just business